# Unix authentication not working using Unix keyfile for one user but working for other

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-keygen

My OS details:

- NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
- VERSION="7.4"
- ID="ol"
- VERSION_ID="7.4"
- PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.4"

I am trying to create a Unix keyfile for one of the defined users. 
But it is not working; password is being prompted. 
I did this one the same way we created a file for another user
on the same machine, but that one is working.

`sftp -i /home/oracledi/.ssh/username1key username1@10.100.11.33`  — Not working

`sftp -i /home/oracledi/.ssh/username2key username2@10.100.11.33`  — Working

What could be the reason for this?

How can I debug this?

The command I am using is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I am new to the Unix world; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this by inspecting files `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/secure`. See what is written in these files when you login (on your computer and on host).

I would also recommend you to check file permissions. Here is an example from one of my hosts, how the permissions of files in `.ssh` directory should be. Type

```
ls -al ~/.ssh/
```

to see files and their permissions and ownerships. they should be owned by user and some writable only by user.

```
-rw------- 1 user user   407 sep 30  2016 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user  1675 mar 15  2013 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   405 mar 15  2013 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 70884 feb 14 08:08 known_hosts
```